# How to sum time in jasper reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I  have created a cross tab jasper report.This report needs to sum the time in every row.
[image]

[Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXw4Q.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Show the code that is failing.

Comment: Do you want to code  or screen short  of cross tab report?

Comment: Both, if you can. Please update the question with all the details that you can provide.